# Unable to click on select option dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I not able dynamically click on each `#cars` option?

```js
let carscount = $('#cars > option').length;
 console.log(carscount);
var x = carscount;
var interval = 1000;

for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    let counter = 1;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cars').click();
        $('#cars > option:eq('+counter+')').click();
        counter++;
    }, i * interval)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is #Select-10? There is no element in your example with that ID. Also, are you just trying to set the selected option?

Comment: Sorry, it was big typo! I fixed the code

Comment: Many browsers don't support events on `<option>`

Comment: This question can be closed. From the close reasons: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0):

Programatically clicking UI controls is not best practise as cross browser / cross device support will vary.  If you want to programatically pre-select an option just do `myList.value = "audi"`

Answer (score 0):

If i got your point you can use this way to change the select's value .. using `.each()` to loop through the options then use `setTimeout()` in the `.each()` and to get the selected value you can add `change` event for the select

```js
var interval = 1000;

$('#cars > option').each(function(i){
  var ThisVal = $(this).val();
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('#cars').val(ThisVal).change();
  }, i * interval)
});

$('#cars').on('change' , function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And with your code you need to make some changes to let it work

```js
let carscount = $('#cars > option').length - 1;
 console.log(carscount);
var x = carscount;
var interval = 1000;
let counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#cars').val($('#cars > option:eq('+counter+')').val()).change();
        counter++;
    }, i * interval)
}

$('#cars').on('change' , function(){
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

> Note: because `:eq()` index starts from 0 and `.length` starts from 1
>   .. you need to `- 1` the `.length`